# HTML form - need user to be able to choose an option from a dropdown list and then also enter a number into another field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for some HTML code for the following:

A form where a user chooses an option from a menu and also enters a number into another field.  Then, depending on their chosen option, I need to perform a calculation that shows up on the screen.  For example:

This is what the form would look like...

What type of person are you?
-Dropdown list gives options(A, B, C)
How old are you?
-User enter a number in this field (user_age)
*Calculate button*

When calculate button is clicked:
If user chose option A, show "user_age" divided by 20.
If user chose option B, show "aser_age" divided by 10.
If user chose option C, show "user_age" divided by 5.

So, a user would chose option A, enter "80" into the age field, and when they click "calculate", the number "4" would appear on the screen.  Can anyone help me with this?  It seems straight forward. Here is what I have so far!

```
<select id="Type" name="Type">
<option selected="selected" value="None">None</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>
What is your age?   <input id="Age" type="number" />
<input id="Age" type="button" value="Calculate" />
```

Comment: you'll need HTML and JavaScript/Jquery, What do you have so far?

Comment: Show us what you have so far. Sounds like you can build the HTML structure and any CSS, and can try something with the javascript and let us know where you need help.

Comment: <select id="Type" name="Type">
<option selected="selected" value="None">None</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>
What is your age?   <input id="Age" type="number" />
<input id="Age" type="button" value="Calculate" />

Comment: I have no idea how to enter a code 'block' on here.. sorry :( @clearshot66

Comment: Hi, the question is too broad at the moment. That's why your'e getting downvoted. I suggest building the form yourself using https://jsfiddle.net/ That way you can point people to a WIP of your form and they can offer assistance. Best of luck :)

Comment: @ClintonGreen Thank you... I thought it was pretty specific as I asked for EXACTLY what I wanted.  Guess not.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Build your HTML syntax

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#calculate').click(function(){
          var dropdown = $('#dropdown').val();
          var age      = $('#age').val();
          var output;
          if(dropdown == 'A'){
            output = age/20;
          }
          if(dropdown == 'B'){
            output = age/10;
          }
          if(dropdown == 'C'){
            output = age/5;
          }
          $('#outputlabel').text(output);
        });   
      });
    </script>
    </head>
          <body>
            <form name='ageform' action=''>
              <label>Age:</label><input type="text" id="age" size ='2'/>
              <label>Option:</label>
              <select id='dropdown'>
                <option value='A'>A</option>
                <option value='B'>B</option>
                <option value='C'>C</option>
              </select>
              <input type='button' id='calculate' value='calculate' />
              <label id='outputlabel'></label>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Test fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u06s92pc/2/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery to the rescue:

```
var useThisLater = $('#selectId').find(":selected").text();
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure how to go about this as a whole.  No clue where to start!